# PyQGIS cannot set proper symbol color

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, symbology

I have created a script to run inside QGIS via the Script Runner.  It works by checking if a layer is already present.  If so, it just reloads the layer but if the layer is not present it loads the layer with the symbol colors I desire. The issue is if the layer is not present it creates/loads the layer with random symbol colors.

If it is present the proper colors appear.

How can I get it the colors I want the 1st time around?

Using QGIS v3.  Below is a sample.

```
def load_veg(self):
    project = QgsProject.instance()
    treeIR = QgsVectorLayer('B:\CHICO\Section_161\CHICO_X17\Vegetation\CHICO_X17_treeIR.shp','CHICO_X17_treeIR')
    
    if len(QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('CHICO_X17_treeIR')) != 0:
        treeIR.reload()
    
    else:
        project.instance().addMapLayer(treeIR)      
        activeLayer = self.iface.activeLayer()
        renderer = activeLayer.renderer()
        symbol = renderer.symbol()
        from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor
        symbol.setColor(QColor.fromRgb(239,27,12)) 

def run_script(iface):
    ap.load_veg()
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to access your layer with activeLayer(), you could just use your already existing QgsVectorLayer instance.
You should also change the renderer before adding the layer to your project.

```
def load_veg():
    project = QgsProject.instance()
    treeIR = QgsVectorLayer(r'C:\Users\greth\Desktop\test\test.gpkg','test')

    if len(QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('test')) != 0:
        treeIR.reload()
    else:
        renderer = treeIR.renderer()
        symbol = renderer.symbol()
        symbol.setColor(QColor.fromRgb(0,0,0))
        project.instance().addMapLayer(treeIR)
```

Alternatively you could add your layer to the project and load an .qml file exported from QGIS afterwards to change the layer appearance.

```
...
else:
    project.instance().addMapLayer(treeIR)
    treeIR.loadNamedStyle('path to qml file')
    treeIR.triggerRepaint()
```